# I want to loop renaming the bot in discord.py rewrite, but its not doing anything when I run something like this

Tags: discord, python-3.7, discord.py, python-itertools

When I run this it doesn't change the nickname of my bot.

`latest_names` is a list of names.

```py
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from itertools import cycle

latest_names = andres.get_latest()
namess = cycle(latest_names)

@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def change_name():
    await guild.me.edit(nick=next(status))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `self.change_name.start()` to start the loop. You should do this in the init() function of a cog.

If it isn't in a cog, then don't add the `self.` bit.